# How to run a procedure having cursor output in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have created a procedure in oracle as follows

```
create or replace procedure jobsfetch
(id varchar2,jobcursor out sys_refcursor) 
as
begin
open jobcursor for
   select * from shop.jobs where job_id = id;
end;
```

I run the procedure in SQL*Plus using:

```
exec jobsfetch('AD_ASST');
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'JOBSFETCH'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

How to execute this procedure since its having only one input parameter?

Comment: try this url https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets

Comment: Error you are facing coz if the number of arguments which you passed to the proc while calling. You proc takes 2 input and in you call you are passing only 1 ,hence you get the error

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
variable CURSOR_LIST REFCURSOR;
exec jobsfetch('AD_ASST',:CURSOR_LIST);
print CURSOR_LIST;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a plsql block:

```
declare
    outCur sys_refcursor;
begin
    jobsfetch('AD_ASST', outCur);
    /* what you need to do with the cursor */
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your procedure has an out parameter, but you don't supply it.

You can't `exec jobsfetch('AD_ASST');`
I recommend putting the whole thing in a plsql block like [Aleksej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654919/1264335).

```
declare
    outCur sys_refcursor;
begin
    jobsfetch('AD_ASST', outCur);
    /* what you need to do with the cursor */
end;
```

This will give you the cursor that you opened in outCur and you can do whatever you need to do with it.